# Truth Table Logic: writing P or Q using only $\land$ and $\neg$

Tags: logic

I am trying to figure out how I can write $P\vee Q$ using only $\land$ and $\neg$. I know that if we have four combinations of T/F, then only one of the four will be false for $P\vee Q$, but how can I do this with only $\land$ and $\neg$?

Answer (score 3):

$$P \lor Q = \neg (\neg P \land \neg Q)$$

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!!

Comment: @Eddie2020 You're welcome!